# Set minimum size of widgets within a custom widget

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, minimum-size

I have a `custumWidget` which displays 3 QLineEdits. These `customWidget`s are stored inside a QListWidget like this:

```cpp
QListWidgetItem* item = new QListWidgetItem();
ui->listWidget->insertItem(index, item);
ui->listWidget->setItemWidget(item, customWidget);
```

I set a minimum size within the `customWidget`:

```cpp
ui->lineEndit->setMinimumSize(50, 200);
```

But when I resize the window, I can resize it even smaller than the stipulated `minimumSize`. Does my `minimumSize` get lost/ignored (for example, in my `customWidget`)?

I'm using Qt 5.1 and C++11.

Answer (score 3):

You should set the size policy for the line edit according to your needs. Take a look at [`enum QSizePolicy::Policy`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum) to find the right size policy.

```cpp
ui->lineEdit->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Minimum);
ui->lineEdit->setMinimumSize(50,200);
```